# What's the difference between a compound type and an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, types, anonymous-types

As the question states above, what's the difference between a compound type and an anonymous type?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18090466/1466627), a compound typed object is defined with a `new {}` statement (below statement).

```
m => new { member = m, split = m.Name.Split(',') }
```

But isn't that the same as when you create an anonymous typed object? Are they both the same thing by different names?

Comment: I don't think that compound type is an official name for an anonymous type with multiple properties. The answerer just made that one up. You should continue to use the term "anonymous type".

Comment: I've never heard of an anonymous object being called a "compound typed object". What you have above is an anonymous object/type. Period.

Comment: You could have asked this to @ Wiktor Zychla itself(Who coined term compound typed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are just different names, yes. The code you put above creates an anonymous type (that is the name you should use, the official one, and the common one).